# Table-level diff and sync procedure for T-SQL

Tags: sql, database, t-sql, synchronization

I'm interested in T-SQL source code for synchronizing a table (or perhaps a subset of it) with data from another similar table. The two tables could contain any variables, for example I could have

```
 base table    source table 
 ==========    ============
 id     val    id       val
 ----------    ------------
 0        1    0          3
 1        2    1          2
 2        3    3          4
```

or

```
 base table             source table 
 ===================    ==================
 key    val1    val2    key   val1    val2
 -------------------    ------------------
 A         1       0    A        1       1  
 B         2       1    C        2       2
 C         3       3    E        4       0
```

or any two tables containing similar columns with similar names. I'd like to be able to

- check that the two tables have
  matching columns: the source table has exactly the same columns as the base table and the datatypes match
- make a diff from the base table to the source table
- do the necessary updates, deletes and inserts to change the data in the
  base table to correspond the source table
- optionally limit the diff to a subset of the base table,

preferrably with a stored procedure. Has anyone written a stored proc for this or could you point to a source?

Comment: A 'perfect' solution could be adopted to SQL Server 2005 and Sybase ASE 15. I guess a TSQL procedure based on system tables is pretty much what I need.

Comment: tables have columns not variables.  so you want code that will take two table names in, compare their columns and if the same, sync the tables? why on earth would you need this? don't you know which tables you want to sync? write the code ahead of time and eliminate the overhead of figuring it out all the time.

Comment: @KM, don't you think that implying that a generic synchronization procedure would have *no use cases at all* is bit excessive? How about when the synchronization is done only once and the code is then thrown away?

Comment: where in your question do you say `generic synchronization procedure`??  Your question is vague at best and certainly does not mention anything about needing to be a solution of any two given tables names.  no where in your question do you even mention that the tables are variable or subject to change.

Comment: @KM. Happier after the edits to the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting question.

you could start from EXCEPT - INTERSECT

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188055.aspx

Here is readymade solution, may help you

http://www.sqlservercentral.com/scripts/Miscellaneous/30596/

Comment: Thanks, the link looks very promising.

Answer (score 4):

SQL Server 2008 features the new [merge statement](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx).  It's very flexible, if a bit complex to write out.

As an example, the following query would synchronize the `@base` and `@source` tables.  It's limited to a subset of `@base` where `id <> 2`:

```
MERGE @base as tgt
USING @source as src
ON tgt.id = src.id and tgt.val = src.val
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET
    THEN INSERT (id, val) values (src.id, src.val)
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE AND tgt.id <> 2
    THEN DELETE
```

Comment: Thanks! Looks like a great feature, flexible and more transparent than a proc with hidden magic. Unfortunately we haven't moved to SQL Server 2008 yet.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it's of any use to your specific situation, but this kind of operation is usually and relatively easily done using external tools (SQL Workbench diff, SQL Compare etc.).
It can even be scripted, just probably not invokable from a T-SQL procedure.